# d3-tree: how to highlight subtrees?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, tree, highlight

Looking at trees like [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/4063570), I was wondering
how could you highlight clades/subtrees of the tree with different colors.
An example of a such a tree is [here](http://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/images/phylogenetics/clade_highlights.gif)

[image]

Is it possible to overlay a rectangle with lower opacity over specific inner nodes?

Any help is much appreciated!